# Shift matrix rows to have maxima in the middle

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, vectorization, shift

This can be implemented with for loops and conditions but is there a fast efficient way to do it using Python and numpy, as I am working with matrices having hundred thousands rows.

As an example we have a small matrix with 3 rows

```
1, 3, 4, 10, 2, 4, 1

2, 4, 10, 1, 1, 1, 2

1, 4, 7, 5, 4, 10, 1
```

As result, I want to have the rows circularly shifted such that the maximum of each row is in the middle

```
1, 3, 4, 10, 2, 4, 1

2, 2, 4, 10, 1, 1, 1

7, 5, 4, 10, 1, 1, 4
```

What I was thinking about was something like this:

```
middle = matrix.shape[1]/2
for row in range(0, matrix.shape[0]):
    max_index = np.argmax(matrix[row, :])
    np.roll(matrix[row, :], middle-max_index)
```

I think argmax can extract all the maxima indexes for all rows. But how to apply a different shift to each row, np.roll doesn't provide such functionality as shift has to be an int and not an array.

Comment: You can convert this to a good question by providing the code that you have tried so far!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would be one `vectorized` approach, assuming `A` as the input array -

```
# Get shape info and the middle column index
M,N = A.shape 
mid_col_idx = int(N/2)

# Get required shifts for each row
shifts = mid_col_idx - np.argmax(A,axis=1)

# Get offsetted column indices
offsetted_col_idx = np.mod(np.arange(N) - shifts[:,None],N)

# Finally generate correctly ordered linear indices for all elements 
# and set them in A in one-go
Aout = A.ravel()[offsetted_col_idx + N*np.arange(M)[:,None]]
```

Sample run -

```
In [74]: A
Out[74]: 
array([[ 1,  3,  4, 10,  2,  4,  1],
       [ 2,  4, 10,  1,  1,  1,  2],
       [ 1,  4,  7,  5,  4, 10,  1]])

In [75]: Aout
Out[75]: 
array([[ 1,  3,  4, 10,  2,  4,  1],
       [ 2,  2,  4, 10,  1,  1,  1],
       [ 7,  5,  4, 10,  1,  1,  4]])
```